# How to encode ~ character to send in POST safely HTTP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sockets

I am using PHP to post this body

`data=a~b~c`

I wat to do this

`data=a~b~xx~c`

I want to give it 3 paramater a,b~xx and c but it reads like this a,b,xx,c . How to encode it. I tried URL encode, HTMl encode but still fail!

Comment: The question is, what are the tildes for? If it's just to seperate the values, don't do that, use a proper datatype like json instead.

Comment: how can i actually use tidal if serfver uses it as a special character, i don't control the server

Comment: [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: @adeneo not working, server decodes!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `%7E` or `&#126;` ?

What method are you using to post this data?